# Can you take a Mutant Familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

When browsing through the different corners of the web, I came across the [Mutant Creature Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/mutant-creature-cr-1). After looking through all relevent channels, I couldn't find a definitive answer as to how this template gets applied.

**Question: is it possible for a Class with a Familiar Feature to take a Mutated Familiar at the start?  If not, can a player use a certain item or the [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar) feat to gain a mutant familiar?**

Comment: Your second link is to material from *d20 Modern*, which is almost certainly unrelated to the material in your first link from *Pathfinder Campaign Setting: Numeria, Land of Fallen Stars*. On that note: did “looking through all relevant channels” include reading the *Numeria* book?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, I only had online resources to look through, and D20 modern was the only resource that talked about mutation without being a mutated monster a DM could use, or the general mutant template mechanics

Comment: I've removed the reference to d20 modern. It's irrelevant, being an entirely different game, and was confusing the point. Areadbhair, hopefully you're across that and understand why it's irrelevant - if not, it'd be best to speak up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, you cannot normally apply any templates to a familiar.

> A familiar is an animal chosen by a spellcaster to aid him in his study of magic. It retains the appearance, Hit Dice, base attack bonus, base save bonuses, skills, and feats of the normal animal it once was, but is now a magical beast for the purpose of effects that depend on its type. **Only a normal, unmodified animal may become a familiar.** An animal companion cannot also function as a familiar. *(PRD, [Wizard: Familiars](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/wizard.html#familiars))*

The exception to this rule is contained within the Improved Familiar feat, which allows you to apply certain templates to your existing familiar based on your alignment and arcane spellcaster level.  As written, Improved Familiar does not allow you to apply the Mutant template, however, it would be reasonable for a GM to allow it, since the Mutant template is fairly new and Improved Familiar was written before the template existed.

I would probably require Arcane Spellcaster Level 3 to match the other templates that can be applied to a familiar with the Improved Familiar feat.

Answer (score -4):

It is possible for you to have a mutant creature as a familiar but honestly I would leave it up to DM's discretion

Comment: Can you give any basis for your claim that it “is possible”? I would expect that the rules specifically say it’s *not* possible. Of course, the DM can change things no matter what the rules say, and it’s worth discussing with the DM no matter what, but that's not really much of an answer because that’s true of pretty much everything.